# Which peripherals remain powered when the raspberry pi 4 model B enters poweroff state?

Tags: pi-4, power-management

When I ran the command `poweroff` in ubuntu 19.10, I noticed that both the Ethernet port and USB ports remain powered even when the rbp4 seemed to have halted. Others using rasbian seem to have had [similar experiences](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104944/rpi-4-consumes-2-5w-when-shut-down).

Which peripherals remain powered when the rbp4B is powered off? and where can I learn more about RBP4 power states? Are they documented somewhere?

**Edit 1:** I just skimmed over the [Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100095_0001_02_en/cortex_a72_mpcore_trm_100095_0001_02_en.pdf) for ARM® Cortex®-A72 MPCore-based microprocessors (supposedly what the bcm2711 is based on). The manual discusses power modes but I couldn't find information on how peripherals like sdcard reader, usb, and ethernet are handled.

Does the BCM2711 have a manual for RBP4 users can access?

**Update:** Through testing, I can confirm that everything **(including the microSD card reader's VDD pin)** remain fully powered. It also seems that the fact of the system halting is not conveyed to peripherals in any way.

Comment: Who knows? Ubuntu uses its own kernel etc. NOT the official Foundation code. Despite its fixation with open source I don't know of any public code. Ask on a Ubuntu support site (if you can find one).

Comment: Mind you if you are using Ubuntu Server (the only "supported" OS) why are you powering it off?

Comment: @Milliways This same behavior was observed in Rasbian, so I don't think it's specific to Ubuntu. Should I edit ubuntu out of this question?

Comment: If you ask a Question about Raspbian (don't know this Rasbian) and present some evidence you might get an Answer. All previous Pi models Pi models remained powered at all times - the Pi4 has power control capability but this was disabled (by default) in later firmware because some Luddites had designed hardware which assumed this. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)
 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100234/8697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely related to the bootloader settings. Setting `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0` or `WAKE_ON_GPIO=1` will keep the 3.3V line powered after a shutdown. The Ethernet chip is powered with 3.3V, so it will remain on indefinitely. You can see active bootloader settings in Rapsbian with `vcgencmd bootloader_config`.

This is not thoroughly documented anywhere as far as I know, but the single most important factor seems to be the 3.3V availability. If it's shut down, the power consumption is greatly reduced, but you cannot wake up your RPi with a GPIO and trying to reset your system in software will lead to a [power-off](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108259/33476). If it remains on, most of the board remains powered, consuming a significant amount of power.

Comment: Yep. i just tested my board and can confirm that all peripherals remain fully powered. A Raspberry Pi Foundation engineer even stated that the 5v rail cannot be turned off.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken 5V rail is more or less directly connected to the power supply input. There aren't many things that are directly powered by 5V though.

Comment: I was under the assumption that USB ports were powered directly from the system's 5V rail. Am I mistaken?

Comment: They are powered though a AP2552 overcurrent protection chip limiting the total USB current to 1.2A.