# How to schedule turning off and on of a pi4 using cron?

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, cron, switches

How to schedule turn off and on of a pi4 using cron ?

Hello, to save power I wanted to schedule precisely when my RPI has to be turned on and off.

I think Cron was a good solution so I try to edit contab and puting the follow lines for my pi4 to shutt off at 12:10 and turn at 12:12 for instance. but I think tvservice just shutt off hdmi ports. Do you now other commands ?

```
12 10 * * * tvservice -o #turn off
12 12 * * * tvservice -p; fbset -depth 8; fbset -depth 16 #turn on
```

But this code doesn't work.

After I saw things online about UUGear as a simple extension to the Raspberry  to have clockwork management but I would like to avoid this solution.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Antoine

Comment: Why do you think cron will be running when the Pi is switched off?

Comment: True ! maybe I should edit a config file ?

Comment: Without external hardware, this is not possible. There is no way to restart the Pi once it has shut down. It also does not have a built-in realtime clock that could be used for this. It may support wake-on-LAN, but I haven't read anything about it.

Comment: Additionally, the Pi does not have a power-save mode. So shutting it down (by software) does not really save power.

Comment: @PMF Shutting down the operating system actually does leave the SoC in a sort of low power state -- it consumes considerably less than a running system would at idle anyway.  Exactly how much I think varies by model and the Pi 4 is a bit special: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/104944/5538

Comment: Note that if you want to use the "most off" option from that post you will actually have to toggle the power externally (eg. a switch on the plug); you would not be able to use the "RUN" pin.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would get a cheap RPi zero W or just zero, or even the new rPi Pico and wire a micro USB to a PCB or breadboard with an NPN 2n2222 transistor and have it give power from the time a to time b and off otherwise. Then you have a handy little IOT switch and since you are not using mains power you can use just a transistor instead of a relay. But relays are cheap too.

Answer (score 2):

#### In the context of ***saving power***:

1. the RPi cannot turn itself OFF - at least [not completely](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114422/what-is-the-minimum-power-required-for-an-rpi-4-in-halt-or-shutdown)
2. the RPi cannot turn itself ON - this requires **external** intervention
3. viewed as a [ROI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment) question, consider the cost of running RPi 24x7x365 is less than [£5 per year](https://www.nimblefins.co.uk/average-cost-electricity-kwh-uk#nogo)

#### Using `cron` - and only `cron`, here's what you **can** do to save power:

1. Scheduling a `shutdown` will help ensure your file system isn't corrupted:

```
12 10 * * *  /sbin/shutdown
```

```
Note: `shutdown` requires root privileges, so run in the `root` crontab (`sudo crontab -e`)
```

2. By itself, [`shutdown` will not reduce power consumption very much at all](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114422/what-is-the-minimum-power-required-for-an-rpi-4-in-halt-or-shutdown), but having prepared the system for removing power, you may then "pull the plug".

This is all `cron` can do for you with respect to saving power. An automated system to turn RPi ON and OFF will require external components.

---

EDIT:

To underscore the *"Return-on-Investment"* point made earlier, this device could be part of a "power-saving" solution:

[image: Outlet Timer]

Plug your RPi power supply into this device, set its timer to switch power off at the desired time, and then just before that time invoke the `shutdown` in a `crontab` as shown above (to help prevent file system corruption).

But here's the best part: The [cost of £7.49](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Defender-Segment-Timer-Switch-Plug/dp/B01CP44AU4) will be [amortized](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/amortize) in less than 2 years.

[image: ROFL]

Answer (score 0):

There are actually extension boards that provide what you want (full power off, automatic restart using a real-time clock). An example is https://joy-it.net/de/products/rb-strompi3, however this one is quite expensive (in the order of $40) and probably only worth it if you need any of the other features it provides (such as a wide range power input, to drive the Pi from i.e. car batteries).