# After shutdown/poweroff command, is it possible to damage a pi (4) by leaving the Powercable in?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, power-supply, electronics, cable

So I have a Raspberry Pi 4 type C 5V 3A adapter plugged into the power extender thingy at all times.

My question is, once you type the `poweroff` command into the terminal and see the device turning off, is it fine to leave the Raspberry Pi 4 as is with the Type C power cable in 24/7 or does it make more sense to unplug the Raspberry Pi 4?

I am asking because of the following concerns:

- Electrical component health
- Fire potential
- Electricity bill/usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to leave it connected, but the power consumption of the Pi may not be what you expect it to be. Unless `WAKE_ON_GPIO` is set to `0`, and `POWER_OFF_ON_HALT` is set to `1` in the bootloader config, the Pi will still consume [a lot of power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/104944/33476).